# why the docker-machine's inner docker version is different from the outside

Tags: docker, docker-machine

why the docker-machine's inner docker version is different from the outside.i use this command to create the default docker machine

```
docker-machine create --driver virtualbox --virtualbox-memory 6000 --engine-registry-mirror=https://2h3po24q.mirror.aliyuncs.com default
```

the different version is below:

```
➜  ~ which docker
/usr/local/bin/docker
➜  ~ docker -v
Docker version 17.12.0-ce, build c97c6d6
➜  ~ docker-machine --version
docker-machine version 0.13.0, build 9ba6da9
docker@default:~$ docker -v
Docker version 18.02.0-ce, build fc4de44
```

Answer (score 1):

The `docker` client on your local machine connects to a Docker API running in `dockerd` inside the VM. The local machine and the virtual machine have independent installs of Docker so the versions can vary. As long as the client supports the servers API, they will work with each other.